# Prove that a specific function is injective...

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

... In the context of the question:

Say we have a set $S$, that contains all the strings with the alphabet $a$ and $b$, i.e. $$S = \left\{a, b, aa, bb, ab, ba, aaa, bab, bba, \dots\right\}$$

Now, say we have a function $R(t)$ that replaces the *leftmost* occurrence of $a$ in $t$ with $b$, i.e. $R(aaabb) = baabb$, and $R(bbaaaab) = bbbaaab$, and so on.

How do we prove that $R$ is injective, or otherwise?

Comment: I think it isn't injective. Because $R(a)=b$ and $R(b)=b$...

Comment: @DoyunNam, thank you; that was short and sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not injective.  Take $s_1 = ab$ and $s_2 = bb$.  Then, $R(s_1) = bb = R(s_2) = bb$.  But, $s_1 \ne s_2$.  So, we have one output mapping to two inputs.  This is just a more exhaustive explanation of Doyun's answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.